# Splunk query formulation for unique records as per specific fields

Tags: splunk

Hi I have a log file that has thousands of records with a field called correlationId.... I am trying to write a search query that will return me total count of unique records by correlationId. Can anyone give some idea about how to formulate the query.

Answer (score 2):

if the field name is correlationId, try

```
index=<index>.. | stats dc(correlationId)
```

this will find the records with unique values of field correlationId, and count them